# How to effectively take an element out of the document flow?

Tags: html, css

I have a table, with many tds. I want to display a div behind this to give the appearance of it having rounded corners. I have called the Div within a th. [Here is a jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/EYwfc/) of the problem.

I thought I could do it using `position: realtive;` and `z-index: -100;` yet it doesn't seem to be what I want.

Thanks to anyone for any help.

Comment: Exactly what is the problem with your current solution? How is it being rendered?

Comment: Oh yes, sorry. It extends to the bottom of the TD, but I want it to be behind everything, not a part of the table. If you alter the height of the div, you'll see it messes with the TD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you’ll need a different approach. For the `<div>` to be the same height as the `<table>`, you’ll need the `<div>` to wrap the table:

```
<div>
    <table>
    ....
    </table>
</div>
```

That’ll also make the `<div>` appear “behind” the `<table>` without fiddling with `z-index`.

From your jsFiddle example, I think you only want the background behind one table column? To achieve this, you’ll need to:

- fix the width of all the columns in your `<table>`
- set the width of the `<div>` to the width of the column you want it to be the background for (or a little wider)
- set the left margin of the `<div>` to the width of the other columns in the `<table>`
- set the left margin of the `<table>` to minus the width of the other columns in the table.

Maybe something like this?

```
<div class="compare-rounder">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <th class="price">Price</th>
            <th class="product">Product</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>$4000</td>
                <td>for this</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

table,
table td,
table th
{
    border: 1px #000 solid;
}

table
{
    margin-left: -500px;
}

.product
{
    width: 500px;
}

.price
{
    width: 50px;
}

.compare-rounder
{
    width: 60px;
    background-color: #f0f; /*bright pink*/
    border: 1px #ccc solid !important;
    border-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    margin-left: 500px;
}
​
```

Comment: You’re most welcome; posted some example code now, which might help.

Answer (score 0):

You should do this I guess :

```
<div class="compare-rounder">
    <table>
    ...
    </table>
</div>
```